# How to make interactive HTML forms?

Tags: html, forms, webforms

How to make HTML forms interactive? Which techniques are best for interactive forms? Any good suggestion where I can learn web forms? I am in learning process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create HTML form more dynamically using **CSS,Javascript** as well as using the **Bootstrap**.It will help you to create a HTML Form with several Features like

1. validation
2. Designing
3. Responsive web Pages etc.

You can go with this link here you can easily get all information about Page Designing..

**https://www.w3schools.com/html/**

Comment: Please do not answer obviously off-topic questions here.

Comment: I am new on stackoverflow I am learning the rules of stackoverflow.next time I will take care of that

Answer (score 1):

A web form is already an interactive piece of content on the page. The user interacts with it. If you want to style it then you use CSS or JavaScript/JQuery. Alternatively, use Bootstrap to style the forms and give them glyphicons and validation. Forms are fairly complex in my opinion. So just stick with the basics until you can at least understand how they are working. Use resources like W3Schools, Mozilla Developers Network (MDN), or places like CodeAcademy, Lynda.com, to learn more.